# I accidentally uninstalled java and now I can't use it

Tags: java, openjdk

So I wanted to remove all the java versions from my computer and reinstall them. So I looked at all my java versions with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --display java
```

And one by one I deleted them with

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headle/bin/java 100
```

Then I tried to install java again with:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

then I tried to run java `java -jar myprogram.jar` and it says:

```
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I tried to reinstall java and it's just saying:

```
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72, or
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.5+10-0ubuntu1
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless  # version 13+33-1
sudo apt install openjdk-14-jre-headless  # version 14~18-1
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u232-b07-2ubuntu1
```

No matter how many times i uninstall and reinstall java etc. what can I do to get java 8 back up and working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `jdk` instead of `jre`. To install 8 version use the next command:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

After this, you could see:

```
$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

If you know where `java` binary is you could do:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java /usr/bin/java`

or add to your `~/.profile` at the end:

`PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin`

Then reopen terminal and check `echo $PATH`. But use your java version instead of 11.

> The JRE is the Java Runtime Environment. It is a package of everything
>   necessary to run a compiled Java program, including the Java Virtual
>   Machine (JVM), the Java Class Library, the java command, and other
>   infrastructure. However, it cannot be used to create new programs.
>
> The JDK is the Java Development Kit, the full-featured SDK for Java.
>   It has everything the JRE has, but also the compiler (javac) and tools
>   (like javadoc and jdb). It is capable of creating and compiling
>   programs.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1906455/10854998)

Comment: Yep it was a path issue. sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java /usr/bin/java  worked for me right away.